# How do I inject content into one instance of a blade template but not another within the same page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

On one page that has two  lists. In each of the lists are a set of buttons to alter the corresponding list item's content. In one list, there is an **edit** and **delete** button; in the other list, there is an **add subcategory**, **edit** and **delete** button. Since both have an **edit** and **delete** button, I was hoping I could just recycle them in one template instead of two and then inject the **add subcategory** button into the one list using `@yield`

However, when I load the page and templates, the **add subcategory** button gets added to both lists. Here's my code:

Main Page Template

```
<ul id="two-button-list">
    <li>
        {{-- list item content --}}
        @include('component.list.alter')
    </li>
    {{-- other list items --}}
</ul>

<ul id="three-button-list">
    <li>
        {{-- list item content --}}
        @include('category.alter')
    </li>
    {{-- other list items --}}
</ul>
```

**component.list.alter** Template

```
<span class="buttons">
    @yield('extras', '')
    {{-- edit and delete button code --}}
</span>
```

**category.alter** Template

```
@extends('component.list.alter')

@section('extras')
    {{-- new subcategory button code --}}
@overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few way to achive this. I've selected the shortes one:

**component.list.alter**

```
<span class="buttons">
    @section('extras')
        {{-- edit and delete button code --}}
    @show
</span>
```

**category.alter**

```
@extends('component.list.alter')

@section('extras')
    {{-- new subcategory button code --}}
@stop
```

The above will override section from the part partial view.